# Sendmail is not working with crontab (bash)

Tags: bash, sendmail, cron

I have created one disk cleanup script which after cleanup sends a status email. now when I run this through command line, it executes perfectly but through cronjob its not able to send staus mail rest the script is working fine though. I have read many solutions in google but nothing is working for me. I am using Bash on my Ubuntu machine. here is sendmail part of my script.

```
export CONTENT="/root/cleanup/cleanup.htm"                                           
export SUBJECT="Disk Space Clean Up Process : Completed @ $date_time"

(echo "Subject: $SUBJECT"
echo "`cat sendmail_list.txt`"
echo "MIME-Version: 1.0"
echo "Content-Type: text/html"
echo "Content-Disposition: inline"
cat $CONTENT
)|/usr/sbin/sendmail -t
```

please help me know the solution...thanks

Comment: Use full path when `cat sendmail_list.txt`.

Comment: Might be worth checking `/var/log/syslog` for anythong untoward. You can filter cron messages out by running `less /var/log/syslog | grep CRON`

Comment: Your step has worked Fedorqui....thanks a lot...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a blank line between the message header and the body.

```
{
    echo "Subject: $SUBJECT"
    echo "$(< sendmail_list.txt)"
    echo "MIME-Version: 1.0"
    echo "Content-Type: text/html"
    echo "Content-Disposition: inline"
    echo ""
    cat $CONTENT
} | /usr/sbin/sendmail -t
```

A couple of other things:

- you don't need a subshell here, so I changed the surrounding parentheses to braces
- since this is bash, there's a shorthand for `$(cat file)` -- `$(< file)`

Comment: Thanks for response.. I used blank line as told by you. but still it is not able to send mail. seems like some environment setups issues while running the jobs through cronjob...but not able to identify the solution.

Comment: Did you do anything with fedorqui's comment?

Comment: Ohh..I just noticed Farmer's comment and don't know how missed fedoqui's....Such a fool I am...Its working now...Thanks everyone..really appreciate...

Answer (score 27):

Please add `/usr/sbin` before sendmail in sh file:

```
/usr/sbin/sendmail "user@domain.com" < file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

The environment variables may be different between the cron job and CLI execution.

You might check for differences between output of "env" command from the cron and from the command line executions.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30611010)

Comment: Thanks for contributing @eadana! It may be helpful to provide a little more detail/clarity around your answer.

Comment: env > /tmp/env.manual.output.txt (run this manually)
env > /tmp/env.cron.output.txt   (run this in script at cron)
then check for differences between output files.

Answer (score 0):

my sendmail wasn't sending email on redhat due to a selinux policy

```
Jun 13 04:08:04 xxxx setroubleshoot[3103271]: SELinux is preventing /usr/sbin/postdrop from connectto access on the unix_stream_socket /var/spool/postfix/public/pickup. For complete SELinux messages run: sealert -l eeffd46d-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
Jun 13 04:08:04 xxxx setroubleshoot[3103271]: SELinux is preventing /usr/sbin/postdrop from connectto access on the unix_stream_socket /var/spool/postfix/public/pickup.#012#012*****  Plugin catchall (100. confidence) suggests   **************************#012#012If you believe that postdrop should be allowed connectto access on the pickup unix_stream_socket by default.#012Then you should report this as a bug.#012You can generate a local policy module to allow this access.#012Do#012allow this access for now by executing:#012# ausearch -c 'postdrop' --raw | audit2allow -M my-postdrop#012# semodule -X 300 -i my-postdrop.pp#012
```

This did the trick as suggested [here](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1281668):

```
    # grep postdrop /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2allow -M mypol
    # semodule -i mypol.pp
```